# How to store a handful of relational data (e.g. user roles) in postgres 9.3?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

What's the best way to store a handful of relational data in postgres 9.3?

- e.g. what roles each user has (editor, publisher, admin, viewer,
  contributor)
- e.g. file extensions readable by app (pdf, txt, epub,
  rtf)

Normally, this would go like...

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id SERIAL,
...
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
id SERIAL,
name VARCHAR(50), -- editor, publisher ...
description VARCHAR(50) -- ideally, UI display would be different than database codename, e.g. "Administrator" for "admin"
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
user_id int,
role_id int,
...
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id)
);
```

The requirements are

- en entity (e.g. user) can have 0, 1, or N items (e.g. roles) assigned, where N<20
- data has to be quickly filter-able (e.g. SELECT all users with role=publisher)

Considering that N<20 though, is there an alternative, effective, easier to work with way to store this? (maybe array or json?) 
If so, how would the schema definitions, INSERT and the above SELECT query look like?

Comment: If you have a large user base, build an index on each FK in user_roles. It is nice to stick to 3nf (as you are doing) and not specify roles on user row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my personal experience there is no better way to store this. It's what relational database engines are built for.

I'm always tempted to use all the cool features of PostgreSQL, too, but after careful analysis the old ways often are still the best.

Joining three tables might be inconvenient, but using JSON, XML or arrays the queries get difficult and messy, too. And often they are a lot slower, because they cannot use indexes as well as simple selects and joins.

If the joins really bother you, you could use a view, but I doubt it'll make much difference.

Comment: How did it go? @user2528332

Answer (score 1):

When working with a RDBMS like postgres, you want data stored in relations.  That's what it's designed for.  Arrays and JSON break this, and make working with the data harder.  If this information is important enough to store in a database, you should design the tables to store it properly.

You may want to also read [this](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/).  It's basically a story about someone who decided to store relational data in in a nosql database, and regretted it.  The same idea applies to storing your relational data in a non-relational db format (like putting json in a column).